# Is it possible to access an app's push notification status from within the app itself?

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I'm making an app which relies heavily on push notifications being turned on, and I know many people who switch them off straight away without checking to see what they will actually do.

Is there a way to access the current on/off status of the app's push notifications, and to then possibly reactivate them in app if they are off? I wouldn't be looking to automatically switch them back on, but instead to say that the user cannot send a message out if they don't have their own push notifications switched on - and then switch them on from there if the user agrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you register for remote notifications on every application start (as recommended by the push notification guide).

The `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol specifies the following error handler that will be called in response to a failure while registering:

`application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`

You could use this method to notify the user about the requirements for your application.